# Check Multiple Rows for a Value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to check the column IsSubmitted in  multiple rows in a table for a a certain user id.

If any of the rows has a 1 for is submitted I return 0   else I return another value.

How do I check the results of this query to see if any of the rows has a 1 for IsSubmitted  if it returns multiple rows?

SELECT IsSubmitted  FROM [Application] WHERE ID = @id

EXAMPLE  this query may return

```
IsSubmitted
    0
    0
    0
    1
    0


    or  

    0
    0
    0
    0
```

it could be any number of rows or only one row.   I need to know if any of them contain a 1.    We have an application where they only have to pay one time and they can submit as many apps as they want, so I need to check and see if they have already paid(submitted).

If they have submitted then i need to take one action, if they haven't then i need to take another action.

Comment: do you have an example of a data set?

Comment: And an example of your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE
  WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Application WHERE ID=@id AND IsSubmitted=1) THEN 0
  ELSE 1  --or some other value
END
```

This can be inserted into the context of a larger query if needed.